# Insufficient permissions clientside while simulator works

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-security

I have the following firestore rules setup where I want to let anyone create a document in the suggestions collection, but only a certain user can update it. The rules look like this:

```
  service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /suggestions/{sugg} {
        allow create, read;
        allow update: if request.auth.uid == 'abc123';
      }
    }
  }
```

When I test this in the provided simulator, it works fine; however after waiting 30 minutes I test in my deployed app and I get the error:

> Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.

In my app I'm doing an `add()` call on the suggestions collection. So in my rules where I specify `allow create`, that should be sufficient. I added `read` in case the returned document would count as a read.

Client: (AngularFire)

```
this.afs.collection('suggestions').add(sugg).then(() => {
  this.submitted = true;
}, err => console.error('Firebase error:', err));
```

Comment: Please add the relevant client code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson there you go

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that Firestore couldn't try to match a `uid` when request.auth was null. The solution was to add some functions:

```
 service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
      }
      function isAdmin() {
        return isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == 'abc123';
      }

      match /suggestions/{sugg} {
        allow create, read;
        allow update: if request.auth.uid == 'abc123';
      }
    }
  }
```